# Absolute vertical position of text after chapter title

Tags: spacing, chapters, koma-script

does anyone know the most elegant way of obtaining a dynamic vertical space after the chapter title according to the number of lines the title takes?

I want the text body to always start at the same vertical position, regardless of whether the chapter title stretches over 1/2/3 lines.

The standard infrastructure such as `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}` or

```
\titlespacing{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right>]
```

from the `titlesec` package only allows for a relative vertical spacing.

So I need something like

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vskip\dimexpr 35mm-\n\baselineskip}
```

where `\n` is the number of lines the concrete chapter title takes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vskip 35mm}

\begin{document}

   \chapter{This is a simple headline} 
   \lipsum[1]

   \chapter{This is a very very long headline taking two or more lines making the
text shift down accordingly}
   \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `titlesec` has a package option called `rigidchapters` which does what you want.  But then, I think `KOMA` does not play nicely with it.  Can you use a standard document class?

Comment: Nice idea! But the problem is, I'm stuck to `scrbook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=35mm]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \parbox[t][0pt][t]{\linewidth}{\raggedchapter\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

   \chapter{This is a simple headline} 
   \lipsum[1]

   \chapter{This is a very very long headline taking two or more lines making the
text shift down accordingly}
   \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

If you need the top edge of the first line of the chapter head aligned with top edge of the text area, you need an extra `\par` at the end of `\chapterlinesformat`. But then an extra height of the first line of the chapter head (e.g. something like `\rule{2cm}{2cm}`) could move the text after the chapter head down. You can avoid this using some extra `\parbox` and `\strut` magic:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}% show the text area for debugging

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  beforeskip=-1sp,% no space or glue before the chapter head and no indent of
                  % the first paragraph after the chapter
  afterskip=35mm,% 35mm (but no glue) after the first line of the chapter head
]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \parbox[t][\ht\strutbox][t]{\linewidth}{\strut
    \parbox[t][0pt][t]{\linewidth}{%
      \vskip -\ht\strutbox
      \raggedchapter\@hangfrom{#2}{\strut #3}}\par
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

   \chapter{This is a simple headline} 
   \lipsum[1]

   \chapter{This is a very very long headline taking two or more lines making the
text shift down accordingly}
   \lipsum[1]

   \chapter{\protect\rule{5em}{5em}This rule breaks everything}
   \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: three example chapters]

If you have chapters with prefix line, you have to redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. See the manual for more information about these commands and their defaults.

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent solution!
Only thing is: if you compare the vertical position of the headline with and without your modification, it is not the same. The `\parbox` you inject puts the baseline of the headline on the first baseline of normal text. But as the font of the headline is bigger, it will grow a bit higher in consequence. The normal \chapter command however, if you set the beforeskip to 0pt, does not align the baseline of the headline with the first baseline, but the top of the headline with the top of the text area. Dunno how to solve this to get the same result...

Comment: You can add `\par\nobreak` to the end of `\chapterlinesformat`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not stuck to the `scrbook` class, the `titlesec` package has the `rigidechapters` for that.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,  openany]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetTracking[no ligatures={f}]{encoding=*}{50}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newlinetospace, rigidchapters]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE\filleft} %\normalsize
{{\Huge\thechapter}\vspace{0.5ex}\\
\titlerule[1.5pt]}%
{0ex}
{\lsstyle}%

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0.5cm}{6cm}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Particles Interaction\\ with Multiphase Fluid \\ and the Applications}

\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But the problem is, I'm stuck to `scrbook`.

Comment: I'm not sure  `titlesec` is fully compatible with `komascript`., and I don't know if it has similar tool as the `rigidchapters` option. Note the effect of this option is the last parameter of `titlespacing` is the vertical distance between the `top` of the title and the following text, whereas the default is the distance between the `bottom` of the title and the following text (hence greater values in the former case).